# DNS errors in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, dns, nameserver

I've been trying to get rid of this DNS error for about a week now but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

The website is `herbelixirs.com`.

The Google Webmaster Tools screen shot is below.

[image]

The DNS errors are below.

http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=herbelixirs.com

[image]

Can someone tell me what this means and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be some DNS configuration issues for your domain at the parent nameserver level, as can be seen [here](http://www.dnssy.com/report.php?q=herbelixirs.com).

This is also causing traceroutes to timeout, as can be seen [here](http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=trace&host=herbelixirs.com), which is indicative that your site may not be reachable by Google.

You'll need to contact your DNS provider's support team (at either your domain registrar, web hosting company, or third-party DNS service) for assistance to resolve your DNS issues, which will resolve the DNS error in Google Webmaster Tools and allow Google to access your site properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is somebody else that appears to have the same problem:
https://serverfault.com/questions/484086/dns-configuration-issues

The problem is caused by extra NS records.  The solution is to remove extra NS records.